# Count the number of times a player plays a game in a different difficulty level

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I have a xml and xslt files like below. And Im showing in a table the gamename and the player name. But now Im trying to do one thing and Im not see how.

I want to show how many times a player played a game in a novice, easy, medium, hard, legend level and the total. For example I want each row like this:

```
GameName | Player Name | NoviceLevels | EasyLevels | MediumLevels | HardLevels | Total
```

I already try a lot of alternatives but Im not having success put this working like this. Do you see how to achieve this?

```
<games>
  <game>
    <gamename>GameTitle 1</gamename>
    <players>
      <player>
          <playername>John</playername>
          <difficultlevel>Novice</difficultlevel>
          <duration>130</duration>
      </player>
      <player>
        <playername>John</playername>
        <difficultlevel>Easy</difficultlevel>
        <duration>210</duration>
      </player>
      <player>
        <playername>Zed</playername>
        <difficultlevel>Medium</difficultlevel>
        <duration>300</duration>
      </player>
    </players>
  </game>
</games>
```

And this xslt:

```
<table>
<xsl:for-each select="//games">
 <tr>
   <th>GameName</th>
   <th>Player</th>
   <th>Beginner</th>
   <th>Beginner</th>
   <th>Medium</th>
   <th>Hard</th>
   <th>Legend</th>
   <th>Total</th>
 </tr>
<xsl:for-each select="game">
 <tr>
   <td><xsl:value-of select="gamename"/></td>
   <td><xsl:value-of select="players/player/playername"/></td>
   ....???
 </tr>
 </xsl:for-each>
</table>
```

What I have is here: http://xsltransform.net/pPJ8LVb/1

Comment: This is a *grouping* question. Do a search - it's probably the most often asked XSLT question here. Note that answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: Please don't tag your question as **both** XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an adaption of what you tried, assuming an XSLT 2.0 processor as it uses `for-each-group`:

```
<html xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xsl:version="2.0">
<table>

        <tr>
            <th>GameName</th>
            <th>Player</th>
            <th>NoviceLevels</th>
            <th>EasyLevels</th>
            <th>Medium</th>
            <th>Hard</th>
            <th>Legend</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="games/game">
          <xsl:for-each-group select="players/player" group-by="playername">
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::game/gamename"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="playername"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="current-group()[difficultlevel = 'Novice']/duration"/></td>
                <td>...</td>
                <td>...</td>
                <td>...</td>
                <td>...</td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/duration)"/></td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:for-each>


    </table>
</html>
```

I haven't spelled out the code for all table cells respectively levels, it should be clear how to do that I hope from the one level spelled out.

I am also not sure whether the approach shown suffices, it assumes for any player there is only one entry for each difficulty level per game, if not, you would need to use a nested grouping by `difficultylevel`.

Comment: Thanks, your code works perfectly. But Im getting this error: ERROR:  'line 144: Unsupported XSL element 'for-each-group'.'. Do you know why can be?

Comment: (Im creating a html file using a xml file in java)

Comment: I clearly said "assuming an XSLT 2.0 processor as it uses for-each-group" so if you are using Java make sure you use Saxon 9 (available in an open source version (so called HE Home Edition) on Maven or from saxon.sourceforge.net).